# If car is going with constant velocity, and hits a man, will the man experience force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Let's suppose a theoretical case where a car doesn't start with rest but with a high velocity enough to kill a man. The car doesn't change it's velocity i.e no acceleration or deceleration and hits a man after a while(Assume car is moving on straight path). Since, velocity is constant, acceleration is zero. So is the force exerted by the car zero Newton? And If so will the man die?

Answer (score 1):

A force is basically a pull or a push. A car that hits a person also pushes on him and so exerts a force.
If a car is moving at all then surely it has momentum. When it hits a man, it exerts force on the man which for an instant changes it's velocity and hence momentum. By Newton's third law, the man equally experiences an impulse/change in momentum while the car nudges him forward. The bottom line is: the car definitely exerts force on the man.
It is important however, to understand that zero acceleration doesn't mean zero momentum. Even though a car moving with uniform velocity doesn't experience any net force but that is not to say it doesn't have momentum. It will not be wise to say F=ma and a=0 so F=0. That equation applies not to the man but the car itself and will only hold up until the car hits the man. (since it was assumed the car was moving with zero acceleration). Once the car hits him, the equation becomes F∆t=∆mv according to Newton's second law. Hope that one helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**: The force exerted by the car is not zero. The man could die when hit by car.

A car moving with constant velocity (zero acceleration) in a given direction doesn't mean that it will not exert a force when hits a man. The force is generally defined as the rate of change of linear momentum of an object in a certain direction
$$F=\frac{d(mv)}{dt}$$

When the car hits the man its velocity is reduced (i.e. car gets retarded) this causes change in linear momentum in moving direction in a certain time. This causes the car to experience force exerted by the man & as a reaction the man experience the force & can die when hit by car.